# How can I add ActivityKit extension for iPhone but not Mac in SwiftUI app?

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval, activitykit

I have a SwiftUI app that is developed for all iOS devices and silicon Mac OS as well.

I have added ActivityKit Widget for the iOS devices and it works well.  But when I submitted to the appStore I got the following error:

> ITMS-90863: Macs with Apple silicon support issue - The app links with
> libraries that aren’t present in macOS:
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ActivityKit.framework/ActivityKit

I don't wish to uncheck Mac because this app will be for Mac OS as well as iOS.  How can I exclude the widget for only iOS to fix this warning?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue in my project:

- In Xcode select the project > your target > Build phases
- In "Link Binary With Libraries" phase add `ActivityKit` and `WidgetKit` if they're not already there
- Change their statuses to `Optional`

After those changes I was able to run the iOS app on macOS.